# working with laravel images dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Controller code,

```
public function postApprove($id)
{
     $application = Move::where('id', '=', e($id))->first();
if($application)
{
    $application->approved = 1-$application->approved;
    $application->save();
  return redirect()->route('driver');
}
}
```

Here is the jscript code,

```
<script language="javascript">
function changeImage() {

    if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src == "http://school.glwh.org/wp-content/uploads/bigstock-vector-green-positive-checkmar-16955600.jpg") 
    {
        document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/1/1/9/2/12065738771352376078Arnoud999_Right_or_wrong_5.svg.hi.png";
    }
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "http://school.glwh.org/wp-content/uploads/bigstock-vector-green-positive-checkmar-16955600.jpg";
    }
}
```

And in view

```
<span><a href="{!! route('approve', ['id' => $user->id]) !!}"><img alt="" 
src="http://school.glwh.org/wp-content/uploads/bigstock-vector-green-positive-checkmar-16955600.jpg" 
        style="height: 85px; width: 80px" id="imgClickAndChange" 
    onclick="changeImage()"  /></a></span>
```

This code changes the dbvalue but when refresh the image get default image.How Can I solve the problem

Comment: Not certain what you are trying to achieve. Toggle the `.src` of an `<img>` element, or set the `.value` of an `<input>` element to the `.src` of an `<img>` element?

Comment: On click image 'ld toggle and store the given value in db (Both actions)

Comment: Should click on element submit form? Can you include rendered HTML and JavaScript that you have tried at Question?

Comment: Yeah I've understand the logic,But is it possible that onclick of image (approve/unapprove) both switching images and change the db value

Comment: I've updated my code

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle the `.src` and `.value` of an `<input type="image">` element by attaching `click` event to element and assigning the function at code at Question as handler

```html
<input 
  id="imgClickAndChange" 
  type="image" 
  src="http://school.glwh.org/wp-content/uploads/bigstock-vector-green-positive-checkmar-16955600.jpg" 
  name="image" 
  value="123" 
  width="320" 
  height="280"/>
<script>
var input = document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange");

input.onclick = changeImage;

function changeImage() {
  if (input.src == "http://school.glwh.org/wp-content/uploads/bigstock-vector-green-positive-checkmar-16955600.jpg" && input.value === "123") {
    input.src = "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/1/1/9/2/12065738771352376078Arnoud999_Right_or_wrong_5.svg.hi.png";
    input.value = "456";
  } else {
    input.src = "http://school.glwh.org/wp-content/uploads/bigstock-vector-green-positive-checkmar-16955600.jpg";
    input.value = "123";
  }
  console.log(input.src, input.value);
}  
</script>
```

Comment: How may i store the value " input.value" in db

Comment: You can place `<input>` element within `<form>` element and submit `<form>` to server

Comment: Thanks.Is there any way to store value in db image  onclick (Without submitting)

Comment: You can  `POST` key, value pair to server using `fetch()`

Comment: Thank you for your code,I'll someelse concept for this using two buttons